# Apache RewriteRule mode not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanna rewrite rule in order to allow ability the path like this:

http://example.com/api/somemethod/
Api is an api.php file that contains api class.

I've rewritten rules in .htaccess, but if i try to link above, i got an error:

```
Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't yet comment on the question (yay karma), I will post one of the more common answers, as this is usually caused by the .htaccess file not being read/followed:

> "try putting junk in your htaccess file. If it's being read, you will
>   get an Internal Server Error when accessing that resource. If it
>   doesn't cause an Internal Server Error, see AllowOverride. This won't
>   work from 2.4 if AllowOverride is used with Nonfatal"

Comment: Thaks, but how can i get rid of error? what do i have to do?

Comment: If your htaccess file is not being read, you have to edit your main configuration and use `AllowOverride FileInfo` to enable mod_rewrite in htaccess files.